# Angular material table in print view

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am creating the project using angular and material, I have used the angular material table in my project. when I print the table it is totally distorted.
Here is table

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" matSort multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%" matSortDisableClear=true (matSortChange)="xxxx($event)">
              <div *ngFor="let column of gridColumns; let i=index">
                <ng-container matColumnDef={{column.Field}} *ngIf="column.Field !='showHide'">
                  <mat-header-cell class="hide-mobile sixCol" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header  [disabled]="isSortingDisabled(column)"
                                   [ngClass]="{'column-right' : numericColumns.indexOf(column.Field)>-1}">
                    {{column.Title}}
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="sixCol"
                            [ngClass]="{'column-right' : numericColumns.indexOf(column.Field)>-1}"
                            [ngStyle]="setmobviewWidth(column.Field)">
                   <span [ngStyle]="xxxx(row,column.Field)"> {{renderColumn(row,column.Field)}}</span>
                   <!-- for mobile devices only -->
                <div class="amount-show-hide hide-desktop" *ngIf="column.Field == 'accountName'">{{renderColumn(row, 'accountNumber')}} </div>
                  </mat-cell>
                  <mat-footer-cell *renderColumnmatFooterCellDef> </mat-footer-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef={{column.Field}} *ngIf="column.Field =='showHide'">
                  <mat-header-cell class="hide-mobile sixCol column-right" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disabled width="25">
                    {{column.Title}}
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" width="25" class="{{getmobiconClass()}}"[ngStyle]="setmobviewWidth(column.Field)">
                    <div [ngStyle]="{'padding-right': [![mobileLayout][1]][1]? '0rem' :'1.4rem'}" >
                       <button [ngStyle]="{'padding-right': mobileLayout? '0rem' :'.3rem'}" class="btn-icon-only pt-0 pb-0" role="button" aria-label="show/hide" type="button" [disabled]="!getIsDisabled(row)" (click)="xxxx(row)" [ngClass]="{'flex-btn-disabled': !getIsDisabled(row)}">
                        <span *ngIf="getIsDisabled(row)==true;else icons">
                          <i *ngIf="renderColumn(row,
                                column.Field)=='true'" class="icon icon-hide cursor-pointer" title="Hidden" ></i>
                          <i *ngIf="renderColumn(row,
                                column.Field)=='false'" class="icon icon-show cursor-pointer" title="Showing"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ng-template #icons>
                          <span>
                            <i *ngIf="renderColumn(row,
                                    column.Field)=='true'" class="icon icon-hide cursor-pointer"  disabled title="Hidden"></i>
                            <i *ngIf="renderColumn(row,
                                    column.Field)=='false'" class="icon icon-no-check" disabled title="Not allowed"></i>
                          </span>
                        </ng-template>

                      </button>
                    </div>

                  </mat-cell>
                  <!-- <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </mat-footer-cell> -->
                </ng-container>
              </div>

              <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="mobileLayout ? mobileDisplayedColumns : dispalyedColumns1" class="hide-mobile"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: mobileLayout ? mobileDisplayedColumns : dispalyedColumns1"></mat-row>
              <!-- <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns1"></mat-footer-row> -->

            </mat-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Below npm to package.json

   - "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
   - "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.2",
     OR you can directly refer npm for this on google
2. Do "npm install"
3. Add class
   class="contentToConvert" to div which you want to print
4. import below dependecies in your .ts file

   - import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';
   - import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
5. Use below function to generate pdf and then print

   generatePdf() {
   let HTML_Width = $('.contentToConvert').width();
   let HTML_Height = $('.contentToConvert').height();
   let top_left_margin = 25;
   let PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
   let PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
   let canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
   let canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

   let totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;
   let firstName = this.candidateData.firstName;
   let lastName = this.candidateData.lastName;

   html2canvas($('.contentToConvert')[0]).then(function (canvas) {
   canvas.getContext('2d');

   let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
   let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
   pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);

   for (let i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
   pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
   pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
   }
   pdf.save(firstName + '*' + lastName + '*' + 'Employment Application');

   });
   }
6. Dont forgot to add click event on button in html like

   <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="CPTURE"
   (click)="generatePdf()">
   Download AS PDF